# How and where to insert Google Translate API key in OmegaT 3.1.3 (Mac OSX 10.9)?

Tags: google-translate, api-key

I use OmegaT 3.1.3, on Mac OSX 10.9
I activated my billing info, Google Translate service, and created a new key.
I inserted my API Key in the file Info.plist, file located under Applications/OmegaT.app right click Show package contents  /Contents/
I added before  the followings lines:

```
<key>apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz</key>
<string>true</string>
<key>google.api.key</key>
<string>**my api key**</string>
```

I reloaded OmegaT but it keeps showing this message:

```
Google Api key not available. See OmegaT manual for instructions. 
<Google Translate v2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately arguments in `Info.plist` are not respected anymore with the way that OmegaT is bundled on OS X. You have to set your key in the actual launch script: `OmegaT.app/Contents/MacOS/OmegaT.sh`

Uncomment this line and replace the key value with that of your key:

```
#GOOGLE_API_KEY="-Dgoogle.api.key=0123456789A0123456789B0123456789C0123456789D"
```

Comment: Note that in OmegaT 3.5 and later, most parameters are in the `OmegaT.app/Contents/Resources/Configuration.properties` file.

Comment: In OmegaT 4.0 and later, the key can be added in Preferences > Machine Translation > Google Translate v2.

Answer (score 0):

After MANY HOURS of poring over old OmegaT versions and instructions of how to insert the Google API key I found that the simple insertion in the Info list worked finally!
I switched to Sierra and things got awry right away after years of working smoothly with the original OT. Probably an update somewhere messed it up.
Make sure you are running the correct Java for your system.
Follow the precise instructions of the utube video that says to insert in the info list and not in the OT.sh file (which I could not find anywhere). Do not follow the code that OT tells you cause it does not work...I tried and tried cutting and pasting it to no avail.
CATguruEn gives a very clear way of how and where:

[link below](https://youtu.be/Nuu34LdEeIM)

watch his video and then insert this:

```
<key>google.api.key</key>
<string>XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
```

where XXXXXX is your API Key (assuming you've set it all up, activated and paid for it)

HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEBODY AND YOU DONT HAVE TO WASTE TONS OF TIME LIKE I DID...